# How to implement a Pygame timed game loop?

Tags: python, pygame

I am looking to write a better game loop in Python using `pygame.time.Clock()`, and I understand the concept of keeping time and de-coupling rendering from the main game loop in order to better utilise the ticks. I also understand about passing time lag into the rendering so that it renders the correct amount of movement, but the only examples I've found are written in C# and although I first thought it fairly simple to convert to Python, it's not behaving.

I've figured out that Pygame's `Clock()` already works out the milliseconds between the last 2 calls to .tick, and I've tried to adapt the sample code I found, but I really need to see a working example written in Python. Here's what I've come up with so far:

```
FPS = 60
MS_PER_UPDATE = 1000 / FPS
lag = 0.0
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True

# Do an initial tick so the loop has 2 previous ticks.
clock.tick(FPS)

while running:
    clock.tick(FPS)
    lag += clock.get_time()
    user_input()

    while lag >= MS_PER_UPDATE:
        update()
        lag -= MS_PER_UPDATE

    render(lag / MS_PER_UPDATE)
```

I'm not sure if this is all worth it in Pygame, or if it's already taken care of in some of it's `time` functions already? My game runs slower on the laptop (expected) but I thought doing this might even out the FPS a bit between my main PC and laptop by de-coupling the rendering. Does anyone have experience doing these advanced game loops in Pygame? I just want it to be as good as it can be...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just take the time it took to render the last frame (called delta time) and pass it to your game objects so they can decide what to do (e.g. move more or less).

Here's a super simple example:

```
import pygame

class Actor(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((32, 32))
        self.rect = pygame.display.get_surface().get_rect()
        self.image.fill(pygame.Color('dodgerblue'))

    def update(self, events, dt):
        self.rect.move_ip((1 * dt / 5, 2 * dt / 5))
        if self.rect.x > 500: self.rect.x = 0
        if self.rect.y > 500: self.rect.y = 0

def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
    sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
    Actor(sprites)
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    dt = 0
    while True:

        events = pygame.event.get()
        for e in events:
            if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return

        sprites.update(events, dt)

        screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
        sprites.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.update()

        dt = clock.tick(60)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If your game slows down below 60 (or whatever) FPS, `dt` gets bigger, and `Actor` moves more to make up for the lost time.

Comment: Wow, easy as that? I think I was over complicating things as usual. Thanks @sloth, that looks like what I'm after.

Comment: I've now got my game running on both the PC and laptop simultaneously and they're now both running at exactly the same speed, even though the PC is at 58-60 FPS and the laptop at 40 FPS which is perfect. Fantastic, thanks again @sloth.

Comment: I should say, rather than passing `dt` straight into the `update()` as it is, I divided it by `MS_PER_UPDATE` which gives a factor (for example - if `dt` is 16ms and `MS_PER_UPDATE` is 16ms (60FPS), then `dt` will be passed in as `1`. If `dt` is 32ms then it's passed in as `2`, etc. and the movement is multiplied by the dt factor).

Comment: I also needed to call an extra `.tick` before the loop to give it the first call, otherwise because there aren't "2 previous calls" then `dt` starts off at something above 9000! This really whacked my graphics when I first did it, so I needed an initial `.tick` call. Viola! All done :)