# How can I call a function each x seconds without stopping the game?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm building a project like a player trys to dodge the bullet, so my game calls `create_bullet()` each time in my `while True` loop.

I don't know how to call that function with an `x` time but without using `time.sleep()` because when I use it, it stops my entire game, even the player movement.

Comment: Time to learn pygame.

Comment: See https://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/game-loop.html, https://eng.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Computer_Science/Programming_Languages/Book%3A_Making_Games_with_Python_and_Pygame_(Sweigart)/03%3A_Pygame_Basics/3.04%3A_Game_Loops_and_Game_States,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54981456/how-to-implement-a-pygame-timed-game-loop and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16301193/whats-the-proper-way-to-write-a-game-loop-in-python

Comment: You could create a [`threading.Timer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#timer-objects) object that will call a function after a certain amount of time has passed without blocking the rest of your game. If you want this to happen more than once, see [threading.Timer - repeat function every 'n' seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12435211/threading-timer-repeat-function-every-n-seconds).

Comment: You could generate a custom event on a set time interval and use that to create your bullets, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60880122/2280890) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

try taking time deltas and check if they are within certain range (5 seconds in this case) you can call your function again. some pseudo code off the top of my head:

```
tic = some initialized value
while true: # your game's loop

  if (time now - tic) >= 5 seconds:
    tic = time now # update tic
  else:
    let the game loop run
  player.display()
  bullet.display()
  # some game logic happens
  # loop ends and goes back
```

`time.sleep()` is not a good way to do it because, as you may already realized, will stop all of the processes running

Answer (score 0):

Use a timer event [`pygame.time.set_timer()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.set_timer) to repeatedly create a [`USEREVENT`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) in the event queue. The time has to be set in milliseconds.
For a timer event you need to define a unique user events id. The ids for the user events have to be between `pygame.USEREVENT` (24) and `pygame.NUMEVENTS` (32). In this case `pygame.USEREVENT+1` is the event id for the timer event.

```py
interval_in_seconds = 2 # 2 seconds

timer_interval = interval_in_seconds * 1000 # 1000 milliseconds = 1 second
timer_event_id = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
pygame.time.set_timer(timer_event_id, timer_interval)

running = True
while running:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

         elif event.type == timer_event_id:
             
             # call function
             my_funktion()
```

The timer event can be stopped by passing 0 to the *time* argument of `pygame.time.set_timer`.